# Selenium is unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I'm trying to automate this website, but I can't make selenium find elements with xpath.

This is the html:

`<input aria-describedby="6076de12_1595321303833_errors" class="form-control" value="" name="6076de12_1595321303833" placeholder="" type="text" data-export-field="" title="Nombre y Apellidos / Name and Last Name">`

This is my code:

```
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('website')
time.sleep(3)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="6076de12_1595321303833"]/input').send_keys(Nom)
```

I've tried with full xpath, but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no ID on the element that you've posted. Did you post the right element and the right code? It's likely that ID is randomly generated... what other locators have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This name is propably not a constant value but the class seems to be so you can try this :

```
 search = driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//input[@class=‘form-control’]”)
```

If it won’t work:

```
 search = driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//input[@title=‘Nombre y Apellidos / Name and Last Name’]”)
```

Comment: Your answer talks about the class being constant but your locator doesn't reference the class. Also, your code has smart quotes aka curly quotes. That code won't compile/run as is.

Comment: Yeah thanks that’s what happens when you try to  help people at night but the xpath is defenitely right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Induce some waits after getting the page so the page loads and you don't miss the element. Grab an input with class form-control and send keys.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control"))).send_keys("AAA")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```